# ios swift table on half a screen

Tags: ios

I'm new to iOS and swift so please excuse this if it sounds incoherent.   What I want is to have a table in the bottom half of the screen and a view with a graph on the top half.  I can do either the table or the graph alone successfully but I can't do both on one screen.  If I put the table first, it takes the entire screen.  If I put a view first, it takes the entire screen and if I put the table on top of it, the table view controller can't find the tableView. The error I get is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException`, reason '[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the nib but didn't get a UITableView
```

I'm guessing it can't find it because the table view is subordinate to the view control.  What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm guessing it can't find it because the table view is subordinate to the view control. What's the best way to accomplish this?

The problem is that you're using `UITableViewController`, which expects it's top-level view to be a `UITableView` instance. Subclass `UIViewController` instead, and implement the table data source and delegate methods as needed. Your view controller should have a plain old `UIView` as its top level view, and you can insert a table view and a graph view as subviews of that view.

Answer (score 0):

Caleb proposes a good old-school solution for the problem.

A more modern and flexible approach would be to use a parent view controller and two child view controllers.  One would drive the graph, while the other would be a TableViewController and drive the table.  The advantages of this come in that it isolates different elements of functionality.  If you decide to change the components for small devices, it becomes trivial to split the two up into a tab controller, etc.